# Choose between various options using probabilities

Tags: c++, random, probability

I've been trying to determine how to choose between various given options with defined probabilities, what I was working on is generating a random number between 0 and 100 and then compare to the probabilities, but I have many probabilities that have the same percentage. For example: the program consists on a baseball game and I have to choose by probability the result of the player at bat.

No advance: .04

Fly Ball: .04

Error: .02

Infield Single: .03

And so on.

```
srand(time(NULL));
double num = rand() % 100;

double Prob = 70;
if( num < Prob)
     cout << num << endl;
```

This is the code I been working with which works fine for one probability, but when it comes to many probabilities and some of those probabilities with the same value it gets complicated.

Answer (score 2):

There's no reason to use double here.
And you just need to sum up the values (more generally, it's the discrete CDF):

```
int num = rand() % 100;
if(num < 4) { /*no advance*/ }
else if(num < 8) { /*fly ball*/ }
else if(num < 10) { /*error*/ }
else if(num < 13) { /*infield single*/ }
else ...
```

Other than that, don't use `rand()`, it doesn't make good random numbers.
See the `<random>` header, especially Mersenne Twister, for a better alternative
(and then, you might even want to use `double`)

Comment: We don't know the rest of the probabilities so int might not suffice.

Comment: @JBentley But rand() generates integers. Checking for `<10.5` or something like that won't do anything better than checking for `<10`.

Comment: Well yes, but as you said, there are other alternative ways to generate random numbers, which include ways to generate types other than int. In the OP's example your point makes sense though. I'm only pointing it out so the OP is aware that int might not be sufficient.